# How to find a conditional distribution of P(X1|X1+X2)

Tags: probability

Given two independent uniform distributions, $X1 \sim U(0,1)$ and $X2 \sim U(0,1)$, I want to find the distribution of $(X1 | X1+X2)$. This rather simple question has been bothering me for a while.

We know that 
$$ f(V=X1+X2) =\begin{cases}
v,  & \text{if 0 $\le$ v < 1} \\
2-v, & \text{if 1 $\le$ v < 2} \\
0, &\text{o.w.}
\end{cases}$$

And we know that 
$$ f(X1, V=X1+X2) =\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{0 $\le x_1$ $\le$1,  $x_1\le$v$\le 1+x_1$} \\
0, &\text{o.w.}
\end{cases}$$

Therefore,
$$ f(X1|V=X1+X2) =\begin{cases}
{1 \over v},  & \text{0 $\le x_1$ $\le$1,  $x_1\le$v$\le 1$} \\
{1 \over 2-v},  & \text{0 $\le x_1$ $\le$1,  $1\le$v$\le 1+x_1$} \\
0, &\text{o.w.}
\end{cases}$$

But this won't integrate to 1. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sketch out the unit square on the $X_1$-$X_2$ plane.  Note that if $X_1+X_2 = v$, then there is an interval on which $X_1$ is uniformly distributed; otherwise, the PDF is zero.

Comment: For instance, suppose that $X_1+X_2 = 1/2$.  Then what is the possible range of values for $X_1$?  It surely cannot be anything greater than $1/2$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [formula for conditional probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Continuous_distributions) we have that

$$ f_{X_1}(x_1|X_1+X_2=s)=\frac{f_{X_1,X_1+X_2}(x_1,s)}{f_{X_1+X_2}(s)}.$$

Since
$$f_{X_1+X_2}(s) = \begin{cases}
s,& s\in[0,1]\\
2-s,& s\in(1,2]\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$f_{X_1,X_1+X_2}(x_1,s) = \begin{cases}
1,\quad x_1\in[0,1]\;\text{and}\;s-x_1\in[0,1]\\
0,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Notice that $s-x_1\in[0,1]$ is equivalent to $x_1\in[s-1,s]$. It follows that

$$f_{X_1}(x_1|X_1+X_2=s) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{s},& x_1\in[0,s]\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{and}\;s\in[0,1]\\
\frac{1}{2-s},& x_1\in[s-1,1]\;\text{and}\;s\in(1,2]\\
0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Notice that if $s\in[0,1]$,
$$\int_0^s f_{X_1}(x_1|X_1+X_2=s)dx=\int_0^s \frac{1}{s}dx = 1,$$
and if $s\in(1,2]$,
$$\int_{s-1}^1 f_{X_1}(x_1|X_1+X_2=s)dx=\int_{s-1}^1 \frac{1}{2-s}dx = 1.$$

Comment: What I'm confused is that I thought the whole integration of conditional distribution must add up to 1, aka $\int_0^s f_{X_1} (x_1|X_1 + X_2=s) + \int_{s-1}^1 f_{X_1} (x_1|X_1 + X_2=s) = 1$.

Comment: $s$ is given and depending on its value the range for $X_1$ changes. What must add up to one is the density of all possible values for $X_1$ given the value for $s$. Suppose $s = 0.5$ for instance, then you know that $X_1\le 0.5$ otherwise $X_1+X_2$ will certainly exceed $0.5$.